# Rename Finder Items

Tags: applescript, rename, finder

I am looking to create a script and was wanting to know if this is something that is possible. I have a little knowledge of applescript. But this one is confusing me.
I have a list of loose files inside of one folder that reads as such.

1111111111 010

1111111111 011

1111111222 012

1111111222 013

1111111222 014

1111111243 020

1111111243 021

Its very random every time. But there is always a 10 digit number that is constant, but I would like to add a sequential number starting with one that resets every time the number changes. So that the file name would look like this.


1111111111_1

1111111111_2

1111111222_1

1111111222_2

1111111222_3

1111111243_1

1111111243_2

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set prev to missing value
    repeat with f in (get files of (POSIX file "/Users/username/folder" as alias))
        set w1 to word 1 of (get name of f)
        if w1 is prev then
            set n to n + 1
        else
            set n to 1
        end if
        set name of f to w1 & "_" & n
        set prev to w1
    end repeat
end tell
```

You could also run a command like this in Terminal:

`cd ~/folder;for f in *;do w1=${f% *};[ $prev = $w1 ]&&let n++||n=1;mv "$f" $w1\_$n;prev=$w1;done`